# Realloc changes the values of the array but array still has the same address in C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I have a question regarding dynamic allocation.

Why do the array values change after using realloc? It works fine if the initial size of the array is greater than the next size `(e.g. 10 20)` but if the initial size of the array is lesser than the next size `(e.g. 20 10)`, the code gives me garbage values.

The code works properly in local side but when I try it on online compilers, it does not work the way it's supposed to.

Is there anything wrong with my code? Or is it a problem with online compilers? And am I using the `realloc` function properly?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void print(int *ptr, int size);
void reallocate(int *ptr, int size);
void assign(int *ptr, int size);

int main(void) {

    int n;
    // Set initial size for array
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int *arr = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    // Assign values from 0 to n-1
    assign(arr, n);
    // Print values assigned
    print(arr, n);
    printf("\n");

    // Set new size for reallocation
    scanf("%d",&n);
    reallocate(arr, n);
    // Assign values again
    assign(arr, n);
    // Print values
    print(arr,n);

    return 0;
}

// Prints values of the array
void print(int *ptr, int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) printf("%d ",ptr[i]);
}

// Reallocates new size for array
void reallocate(int *ptr, int size) {
    ptr = realloc(ptr, size*sizeof(int));
}

// Assigns values from 0 to n-1
void assign(int *ptr, int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) ptr[i] = i;
}
```

I hope for your responses.

Comment: Parametets in C are passed by copy. So in `reallocate` you just discard the new pointer returned by the `realloc`, while you continue using the now invalid pointer outside of that function.

Comment: You need to return the pointers from those functions.

Comment: Hint: what does `void f(int i) {i=5;} int main() {int x=7; f(x); printf("%d\n", x);}` do?

Comment: Why create reallocate instead of realloc?